Unable to add the Anvil network (the corresponding node is running on Gitpod) to my MetaMask
I just started learning Foundry and tried to add the Anvil network to my MetaMask. However, when I input the RPC URL, it keeps showing me the following error:
Could not fetch chain ID. Is your RPC URL correct?


I'm suspecting that this is happening because I'm using Gitpod and its terminal to run Foundry and Anvil instead of VS Code.
Do you have any solution for this issue?

You need to configure the port visibility of the corresponding port (i.e., 8545) in your Gitpod by changing it from private to public. This will make the RPC URL of the Anvil node running on Gitpod accessible to your MetaMask wallet.
